# c# How to click button using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

I tried to click 'Sign In' button.
but It doesn't click at all.
my code is below.
Can anybody help me?

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@name='ctl00$MainContent$LoginForm$LoginButton' and @value='sign in']")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement Submit { get; set; }

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void LoginToApplication()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Submit.Click();
     }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of these below mentioned `xpath`.

```
//button[text()='sign in']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `text` method along with `<button>` tag.

> OR

```
//button[@class='color'][text()='sign in']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `class` attribute and `text` method along with `<button>` tag.

> OR

```
//button[@type='button'][text()='sign in']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `type` attribute and `text` method along with `<button>` tag.

**Suggestion:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.